# ConnectException cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: local.crm.test.com

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, curl

[image]

Facing issue as attached screenshot in laravel local system only, I am using docker container for project

Comment: Any one can help to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed follow below steps

```html
//login with docker
sudo docker exec -it crm-container /bin/bash

// open host file 
vi /etc/hosts

// add your local url 

127.0.0.1  local.project.com
```